# How to print PDF or an image from a page

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET app (it uses DevExpress v 10.2). There is a button called PRINT on a page. When the button is clicked the application should:
1. extract a file from its DB. The file is either PDF or JPEG (the application knows its type in runtime only) 
2. TO PRINT OUT the file. Some ‘preview’ should be shown to user during this

The question is – how to implement this (the item ‘2’)? There is a well-known method to print out an image using JavaScript like the following:

```
function DisplayPrintPopup(html) {
    var win = window.open('', 'popup', 'toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=500,height=500,scrollbars=yes');
            self.focus();
            win.document.open();
            win.document.write('<head><style></style></head><body>' + html + '<style></style></head><body>');
            win.document.close();
            win.print();
            win.close();
}
```

This could be Ok for me. But what to do when a file is  PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just print an element from you page where strid=id of the element you want to print,

before the print is possible to view a preview:

```
function CallPrint(strid) {

    var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=800,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
}
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1034884.aspx/1